# Recording with beep overlay in FreeSWITCH

Tags: freeswitch

We are experimenting with Freeswitch recording for outbound dialling. Currently stuck with two issues after reading many posts and issue lists:

1. Not able to play the beep tone to the receiver
   If I use  only the beep tone is heard for the receiving party.

If I use  the beep tone is not heard to the receiving party but present in recording.

2. In the case of call transfer 2 recording files are generated. Is there anyway to ask freeswitch to merge them into one file? 
   Can RECORD_APPEND or Post Processing Recordings in the Dialplan will be an option to try out?

Comment: So you can't play a beep tone to a receiver and then record their voice??

Comment: The receiver hears only the beep tone and nothing else. Even if we are not recording the behaviour is same when we use displace_session:
<action application="displace_session" data="tone_stream://%(100,15000,800);r loops=-1 mux r" />